# are there any conventions for using MVC in games? (is there benefit)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Do game developers typically use MVC when working with cocos2d?  Or does that paradigm not really fit well with the framework?

I come from Rails, and have a very different understanding of MVC than how Apple does it with the native stuff-- but I am wondering if typically iOS devs are trying to work in an MVC paradigm even with a framework like cocos2d...  I'd also like to get an idea of what it might look like to use MVC, and what benefits would be seen?

A game I am currently working in is more modularly designed, and I've been trying to imagine how I might do MVC with it, but it seems like it would just end up with a lot more files, a lot more code, and not really worth it...  So I would love to get some feedback from the community on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question: No. More [background info in this thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/why-are-mvc-tdd-not-employed-more-in-game-architecture).

MVC is good design for user input driven programs which you want to decouple from the business logic (model). To avoid the two to talk with each other directly, you introduce the controller as the mediator between the two.

In games however things are different. A game isn't waiting for user input most of the time, and the model is often lightweight (a couple variables) yet often requires knowledge about the entire system (collision with other objects, AI checking what other objects are doing).

A game keeps moving forward the game state (model) every frame and it keeps rendering the view every frame, regardless of user input. User input is more like a continuous stream of events as well, specifically in action games. So typically model and view are often tightly coupled, although most game developers at least try to define clear boundaries between the two layers. It is also a compromise to performance since (strict) MVC can add quite a bit of overhead.

Instead of MVC, a much more commonly used design pattern in games is [component based development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering). Often game objects are largely similar, but can have subtle differences in behavior, abilities, weapons, hitpoints, immunities, speed, and what not. Instead of hardcoding, this kind of behavior is added to a game object as a component, which then acts on the object itself. It's somewhat similar to cocos2d's actions, but different in that components typically are active all the time, can be disabled/paused, and are not just solely used for animation but also game logic (ie reducing incoming damage via a shield component).

Comment: Come to think of it, MVC does apply well to game engine design and it's often implemented as such, but rarely called MVC. Unfortunately, cocos2d isn't built with MVC in mind.